# For some users documents keep opening in browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have the following behaviour with a couple of our users.

When opening a document from our sharepoint 2010 site the document always opens in de browser first.

On site collection level as on library level the settings have been set so documents open in Word or Excel immediately. And this works for the biggest part of our users (120). But for about 3-5 users it doesn't work.

I am suspecting browser or OS settings, but I have no idea where to look.

The SP site is running on SharePoint Enterprise 2010 with CU Feb 2013.
The users with the problems are running Windows XP SP3 with IE8.

Comment: Which version of Office are those users using? Are there users without problems also running XP SP3/IE8 and the same Office version?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it. All users have Office 2010 Prof Pro SP1.
About 75% of the users without problems are running XP SP3/IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we found out to fix this behaviour.

By doing a Office repair.

The strange thing was, that even when the Web Apps feature was disabled on site collection level, the document still opened in the browser for editing. Weird stuff...