# Excel document opening in web view even though default is to open in program

Tags: 2010, document-library, excel

I have a document library with one Excel spreadsheet in it. The document library's settings are such that the spreadsheet should be opening in each client's Excel program, not in Excel Web View. I have one user, however, who is unable to open the spreadsheet because it opens in Web View for him and the document has properties that aren't supported by Web View. The option for him to open in Excel itself does not work--nothing happens. It needs to open in Excel by default, not Web View, for this user. The user is using IE 11 and does have Office 2010 installed. I'm out of ideas. What could the cause be?

Comment: sorry for pointing out the obvious, but does the user have excel installed? can you do "edit in microsoft excel"? is he using internet explorer? also, your description does not match your post title (result: nothing happens VS opens web view)

Comment: Just updated the OP, hope that helps answer your questions. Yes, using IE 11, yes, has Office 2010 Standard installed.

Comment: if it is a single user scenario I would recommend repairing the office 2010 install.

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. He still has the same thing happen. I logged in on the computer and it worked as expected, it's only his account that has the problem.

Comment: most interesting. you can try clearing out the "microsoft upload center" and also run the IE fix tool. http://support.microsoft.com/mats/ie_performance_and_safety/ you can also ask the user to log somewhere else to understand if it is machine or account related. maybe in another machine the same account works (local cache). anyway, you would narrow down the possibilities

Comment: btw, make sure you restart after reintalling office

Comment: possible duplicate of [For some users documents keep opening in browser](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71682/for-some-users-documents-keep-opening-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

From previous experience, here are some topics to help mitigate and/or solve office integration problems:

- reinstall office and restart (same behavior below)

[For some users documents keep opening in browser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71682/for-some-users-documents-keep-opening-in-browser)

- clear out microsoft upload center
- reset/repair IE

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/ie_performance_and_safety/

- upgrade to the next available version of IE (or downgrade to previous if already latest)

Answer (score 0):

Are the SharePoint Protocol Handlers (add-ons) installed in IE? They come with the Office Installation but only when you have specifically selected to include the SharePoint Tools in the installation (part of Shared Tools).

I'll just include the link to the Office support page, that won't disappear and to copy paste is to much.

https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Fix-problems-opening-documents-in-SharePoint-libraries-31329FA1-4AD0-47FC-95D8-BB0C5B12A536